# How to run node server if I already have apache instaled?

Tags: node.js, apache, express

I'm trying to run a express server but I already have apache running on my localhost. How can I alternate between both servers?

Comment: you can run apache and node in different ports

Answer (score 0):

Use a other port than 80

```
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Example app listening on port ${port}!'))
```